# Error: Could not determine java version from '12'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

How to fix the following android build issue

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '12'.

Answer (score 0):

Change gradle wrapper distributionUrl version to latest i.e in my case I replaced `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` with `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`.